# How to create Network graph using Topics as Target and list of words as Nodes in Tableau

Tags: networking, graph, tableau-desktop

I am seeking guidance on how to create a Network Graph in Tableau. I have a dataset consisting of Topics and sentences that are associated with those Topics. I have already processed the data by applying tokenization, stop word removal, and n-gram techniques to convert the sentences into words. Now, I want to represent the Topics as the target nodes and the words (unigrams) as the source nodes in a network graph. Can anyone provide any suggestions or recommendations on how to build this network graph using Tableau? Thanks

Comment: I'm a big fan of Tableau and have used it daily for years. Its my "go-to" tool for data visualization. Still, in this case, I'd suggest looking at other tools that designed for network graphs instead of using a general business graphics package like Tableau. You can make network graphs in Tableau, but it is not what it was designed for, so it requires alot of effort (primarily to determine the placement for nodes)  But If you do have x, y positions calculated for the nodes, then displaying them in Tableau will be easy.

Comment: OTOH - One approach you might want to consider is to couple Tableau with a dashboard extension that add's new capabilities (such as network graphs) Look through the extensions gallery https://extensiongallery.tableau.com/extensions to see options